# Is the order of use of perl modules followed when evaluating subroutines?

Tags: perl, module

I have a perl module that has a frequently used subroutine. For a specific set of scripts I need to override this subroutine so i created another module that has the new implementation. Does anyone know if the call order of the perl modules are always followed?

Ex.:

`one.pm`:

```
 sub temp{   print “hi”; }
```

`two.pm`:

```
sub temp{   print “hello”; }
```

`sample.pl`:

```
use one; use two;

temp();
```

I have tested this and it prints “hello” as expected. But I wanted to make sure that this is always the case. Is the evaluation of imported modules in order all the time?

Comment: `use warnings`.

Comment: @mob redefinition by importing the same function twice does not warn.

Comment: Im also using use warnings. No warnings for this.

Comment: `use warnings` inside `one.pm` and `two.pm`

Comment: Re "*Im also using use warnings. No warnings for this.*", That's not true. First of all, the code you posted doesn't even compile. Once you fix that (by adding `1;` to each module and using the wright quotes), it issues the following warning: `Subroutine temp redefined at two.pm line 1.`

Comment: @Grinnz, Nothing's being imported

Comment: @ikegami I was perhaps erroneously assuming these were exporting modules with their own packages (clearly they aren't the actual code if anything is currently working), but your answer covers well what do to if that's not the case.

Comment: @Grinnz, We could speculate all day about the code actually ran, but it's obviously different than what they posted. (Why do soooo many people falsly claim "this code outputs that".) I was just saying mob's advice shouldn't be discounted in this situation (or in general). But your first comment did prompt the addition of the bottom section of my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You should not write modules like that! Your just going to get into problems, including the one you're asking about. Any file loaded using `use` should have corresponding `package`. And they must end on a true value. (Your code doesn't compile because you failed to do so.)

Before I got on, let me mention that you should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. Also note that lowercase module names are traditionally used for pragmas, modules that change how Perl itself behaves. It's a poor practice to use lowercase module names for other purposes.

Back to the point. At a minimum, you need the following:

`One.pm`:

```
package One;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub temp { ... }
1;
```

`Two.pm`:

```
package Two;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub temp { ... }
1;
```

The script would now look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use One qw( );
use Two qw( );
One::temp();
Two::temp();
```

And now you see that your problem is moot; there's no question about which sub is called.

---

But, what if you didn't want to prefix all the calls with `One::` or `Two::`? We can do that!

`One.pm`:

```
package One;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( temp );
sub temp { ... }
1;
```

`Two.pm`:

```
package Two;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( temp );
sub temp { ... }
1;
```

The script would now look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use One qw( );
use Two qw( temp );
One::temp();
Two::temp();
temp();         # Calls Two::temp() because we imported temp from Two.
```

---

If you somehow did the following or equivalent, the last one would win out.

```
use One qw( temp );
use Two qw( temp );
```

That's why it's good to always list the subs you import. Don't use

```
use Foo;         # Import default exports
```

Instead, use

```
use Foo qw( );   # Only import the listed exports. (None, in this case.)
```

If nothing else, it also makes it a lot easier to find subs and their documentation when maintaining the module.

Answer (score 3):

The last one you compile wins, and `use` and `require` statements run in order from top to bottom (including any nesting inside modules that you include).

In this case, you have two module files, neither of which declare a package. Since they don't declare a package, they both use the default package `main`. Everything these modules define will show up in the `main` package.

Likewise, your program is also using the default package `main`, which is how is knows there is a `temp` subroutine. Since you loaded *two.pm* last, that's the definition that wins.

Now, let's fix up the code in your question because it doesn't actually work. Neither of those modules will load because neither returns a true value.

Both modules now have the same code because I can use the `__FILE__` token to tell me which code ran:

*one.pm*:

```
sub temp { print 'From ' . __FILE__ }
1;
```

*two.pm*:

```
sub temp { print 'From ' . __FILE__ }
1;
```

*temp.pl*:

```
use lib qw(.);
use one;
use two;

temp();
```

Running this outputs the message from *two.pm* because that's the last one defined:

```
$ perl temp.pl
From two.pm
```

Run your program with warnings and you'll see there's a redefinition (which in this case is intentional):

```
$ perl -w temp.pl
Subroutine temp redefined at two.pm line 1.
From two.pm
```

The trick, then, is to ensure that your new code always comes last. One way to do this is to load the old module from the new one:

*two.pm*:

```
use one;
sub temp { print 'From ' . __FILE__ }
1;
```

I won't go any further with your example because I figure it's not your actual situation. I do write about these sorts of things in [Effective Perl Programming](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com) though.

Comment: In your first `perl -w temp.pl`, did you meant to omit the `-w`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A [use statement](https://perldoc.pl/functions/use) is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

And Perl runs all compile time code (BEGIN blocks and use statements) in the [order it appears](https://perldoc.pl/perlmod#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END) (but before any runtime code is executed):

> You may have multiple BEGIN blocks within a file (or eval'ed string); they will execute in order of definition.

What creates the subroutine in the current package is usually that module's [import method](https://perldoc.pl/functions/import), which will override any existing subroutines with those names at the time it runs.

Comment: Re "*but before any runtime code is executed*", Before any other code is compiled, even. `use one;` executes `one.pm` before even parsing `use two;`